# How to subtract from each number in a comma delimited string?

Tags: sql, excel, split, subtraction, delimited

I have a table with a string field where than can be one number or mulitple numbers (delimited by a comma).  I need to find the difference between the values (when converted to an integer) and an unspecified value.  For simplicity sake for this question, I'll just say the value to be compared is a static value of 10.

Example Table:

`iId      vchStringNumbers  vchSubtractedStringNumbers
 1        20, 30, 40
 2        50
 3        20`

Desired Results:

`iId      vchStringNumbers  vchSubtractedStringNumbers
 1        20, 30, 40        10, 20, 30
 2        50                40
 3        20                10`

Is there a way to accomplish this in SQL?  If it would be eaiser in excel or something like that, feel free to answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place you **CS** data in an Excel column, Select the cells and run this tiny **VBA** macro:

```
Sub SubtractCSV()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, ",")
        For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            ary(i) = CLng(Trim(ary(i))) - 10
        Next i
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(ary, ",")
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this in Excel and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If one has access to Excel 2019 or Excel O365, one could also use (in `B2`):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")-10)
```